# Dynamodb updateItem immediately after putItem causing overwritten

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

1. putItem ({ a: "123", b: "456" })
2. execute a function which takes < 50ms
3. updateItem (update the item of the first step with b = "789")

Expecting the item to be updated, yet, I found out in the log that updateItem triggered an INSERT item event, which overwrote the item that's being written by putItem. So the end result is {b: "789"}

I wonder how I can ensure the item is fully written in step 1 before executing step 3?

Comment: Do you have any trigger associated with your dynamodb table?

Comment: Please share the code which exhibits the described behavior, otherwise it'll be difficult to figure out what's wrong there.